# How to subscribe a void method with no parameters to a static event(Action) that is in different class at runtime using Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, static, delegates, runtime

So far I have been able to add any method that matches this signature `(Action<ILoginSession>)`successfully in the `IsLoginCallback(MethodInfo method)` method. But I tried using `var runtimeDelegate = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), null);` with a null because the class is static but I keep getting an error. Is it possible to subscribe a void method with no parameters at runtime to an static event Action with no parameters? I have found similar questions but they used an instance of a class to get the static event but in my case the class is also static so I can't the type for a proper reference. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
    public static void AddLoginRuntimeCallbackMethods()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static))
            {
                if (method.ReflectedType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(VivoxManager))) continue;

                if (Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(LoginCallbackAttribute), false))
                {
                    if (IsLoginCallback(method)) continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsLoginCallback(MethodInfo method)
    {
        var runtimeDelegate = (Action<ILoginSession>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<ILoginSession>), null);
        if(method.GetCustomAttribute<LoginCallbackAttribute>(false) != null)
        {
            switch (method.GetCustomAttribute<LoginCallbackAttribute>(false).action)
            {
                case LoginAction.LogginIn:
                    VivoxLogin.VivoxLoggingIn += runtimeDelegate;
                    return true;
                case LoginAction.LoggedIn:
                    VivoxLogin.VivoxLoggedIn += runtimeDelegate;
                    return true;
                case LoginAction.LoggingOut:
                    VivoxLogin.VivoxLoggingOut += runtimeDelegate;
                    return true;
                case LoginAction.LoggedOut:
                    VivoxLogin.VivoxLoggedOut += runtimeDelegate;
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't pass `null`, just the `Action` Type object

Comment: I have tried just passing typeof(Action) and that doesnt work either for some reason. @Charlieface

Comment: Please supply the definitions of the methods you are trying to create delegates for, I would expect them all to **exactly** match the following (ignoring actual names and whether public/private) `static void whateverMethodName(ILoginSession whateverParamName)`. Please also say what the error message is